# Airflow - Set retries of operator using Jinja template

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I have a set of Airflow DAGs, each with a set of tags associated with them. I also have a PythonOperator which is used by all of my DAGs.

I need to set the `retries` parameter of the Operator if the DAG has a specific tag applied, and not otherwise.

The code looks something like this:

*dag.py*

```
from common import tasks

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.helpers import chain

dag = DAG(
'test_retry_dag',
tags=['abc','xyz'],
default_args=default_args,
schedule_interval='* * * * *',
)
    

with dag:
    chain(*tasks())
```

*common.py*

```
def foo(job_name):
    raise Exception()

def tasks():
    return [PythonOperator(
        task_id='auto_retry',
        retries='{{5 if "abc" in  dag.tags else 0 }}',
        python_callable=foo
    )]
```

Since `tasks` is defined in a separate module I don't have access to the DAG object there (passing it as a parameter is not feasible as it would involve making changes in every DAG in a very large codebase. Hence I feel using Jinja templates is the way to go, however the code above doesn't work and I think the way I'm using the template is wrong.

Can someone please help me out?

**Note**: I'm using Airflow 1.10, and updating to Airflow 2 is not possible for me at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in BaseOperator code, then you will find that creating an operator instance (in your case PythonOperator) without passing the dag parameter in constructor, gets its value from `settings.CONTEXT_MANAGER_DAG`.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.15/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L420-L421

Given the usage you described for tasks method, it looks like it always uses the context dag. Then you can change it to do the following.

```py
from airflow import settings

def foo(job_name):
    raise Exception()

def tasks():
    dag = settings.CONTEXT_MANAGER_DAG
    return [PythonOperator(
        task_id='auto_retry',
        retries=5 if "abc" in dag.tags else 0,
        python_callable=foo
    )]
```